# Exit status of child spawned in a pipe

Tags: perl

Simple question but I cannot find a good answer - here goes with an example:

"world.pl" spawns "hello.pl" in a child and processes its stdout. "world.pl" needs to know the exit status of "hello.pl". Making a system call is not an option, since "world.pl" needs to process the stdout of "hello.pl". I am also trying to avoid fork(). Question: How can "world.pl" find the exit status of "hello.pl"? Using perl v5.12.4 on Darwin, if it matters. Thanks in advance, - M.

```
#!/opt/local/bin/perl -w
## hello.pl <name> [more names]
exit 1 if ($#ARGV < 0);
foreach (@ARGV) { print "Hello, $_\n" }
exit 0;
```

The other part ...

```
#!/opt/local/bin/perl -w
## world.pl name [more names ...]
open (FP, "./hello.pl @ARGV |") or die "$0: Cannot open pipe: $!\n";
while (<FP>) { print }
close FP;
my $status = 0; # Want this to be exit status of the process "hello.pl"
exit $status;
```

Comment: Try Run3: http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/IPC-Run3-0.046/lib/IPC/Run3.pm

Comment: `exit 1 if ($#ARGV < 0);` can be written `exit 1 if !@ARGV;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my $status = $?;
```

But you won't be able to follow up with

```
exit $status;
```

because the number will be too big. I've seen people do the following, but it signals success for some failures.

```
exit( $status >> 8 );   # XXX BAD!
```

I recommend what `bash` does:

```
exit( ($status & 0x7F) ? ($status & 0x7F) | 0x80 : $status >> 8 );
```

---

By the way, you fail to correctly build a shell command.

```
$ world.pl 'von Perl' meow
Hello, von
Hello, Perl
Hello, meow
```

Either use String::ShellQuote or use the multiple arg form of `open |-`.

```
open (FP, '|-', './hello.pl', @ARGV)
```

With fix:

```
$ world.pl 'von Perl' Meow
Hello, von Perl
Hello, Meow
```

Comment: Thank you for the syntactic bash guidelines, but they do not answer my question. Let me rephrase: "How can a Perl parent filter the stdout of its child as long it is available and examine this child's status after it exits"?

Comment: Yes it does. `my $status = $?;`

Comment: Wonderful, that is the answer I am looking for. Thank you once again, - M.